# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Tags: java, swing

I wanted to create a simple snake game for two players. When i started the application, firstly main window welcomed us.

Then i chose number of player from menu bar and i expected that the game should run according to the number of players. When i clicked one player or two players, newgame method was called and it also started timer which was called gameTimer. But in Timer, chargeSnake and disChargeSnake method were not working properly. They didn't create snake graphics and gave some errors.

I would appreciate if you could help.

Thanks.

My Panel :

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Grafik extends JPanel
{

    public Point feed;
    public boolean isThereFeed;

    private Color feedColor = null;
    private Color backgroundColor = null;
    private int x_start=0;
    private int y_start=0;

    private Boolean chargeSnakestate = false;
    private Boolean dischargeSnakestate = false;
    private Boolean putFeedState = false;
    private Color snakeColouuuur = null;


    public Grafik(){
        System.out.println("inside of grafik const"); 
        feedColor = Color.RED;                  
        feed = new Point();                     
        backgroundColor = Color.PINK;        
    }


    public void createGraphicYard()
    {        
        System.out.println("inside of creategraphicsyard"); 
        setBackground(backgroundColor);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,350));
        setBounds(0, 50, 400, 350);
        setVisible(true);
    }

     public void chargeSnake(int x, int y,Color snakeColor)
     {  
         System.out.println("inside of chargesnake"); 
         repaint(x_start,y_start,10,10);
         chargeSnakestate =true; 
         x_start = x;
         y_start = y;
         snakeColouuuur = snakeColor;
         repaint(x_start*10,y_start*10,10,10);
         System.out.println("chargeSnake1 : "+ snakeColouuuur+"   "+x_start+"   "+ y_start );
     }

     public void dischargeSnake(int x, int y)
     {
         System.out.println("inside of dischargesnake"); 
         repaint(x_start*10,y_start*10,10,10);
         dischargeSnakestate =true; 
         x_start = x;
         y_start = y;
         repaint(x_start*10,y_start*10,10,10);
     }

     public void putFeed(int x,int y)
     {
         System.out.println("inside of putfeed"); 
         repaint(x_start*10,y_start*10,10,10);
         putFeedState =true; 
         x_start = x;
         y_start = y;
         repaint(x_start*10,y_start*10,10,10);
     }


     public boolean isSnakeTookFeed(int snakeX, int snakeY)
     {
         System.out.println("inside of isSnakeTookFeed"); 
         boolean b=false;
         if((feed.x==snakeX)&&(feed.y==snakeY))
             b=true;
         else
             b=false;
         return b;
     }

     public void specifyFeedCoordinate()
     {
         System.out.println("inside of specifyFeedCoordinate"); 
         List<Integer> possiblePlacesX = new ArrayList<Integer>();
         List<Integer> possiblePlacesY = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        Dimension size = getSize();
        int imageType = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB;
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(size.width, size.height, imageType);
        Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
        paint(g2d);

         for(int iy=0;iy<350;iy+=10)
         {
             for(int ix=0;ix<400;ix+=10)
             {
                 if ((Color.WHITE.equals(new Color(image.getRGB(ix+5, iy+5)))))
                 {
                     possiblePlacesX.add(ix / 10);
                     possiblePlacesY.add(iy / 10);
                 }
             }
         }
         Random random= new Random();
         int rnd=random.nextInt(possiblePlacesX.size()+1);
         feed.x=possiblePlacesX.get(rnd);
         try {
            Thread.sleep(25);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         feed.y=possiblePlacesY.get(rnd);
     }

     public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
         System.out.println("inside of getpreffered size"); 
         return new Dimension(350,400);
     }

     public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
         super.paintComponent(g);
         if(chargeSnakestate)
         {           
             System.out.println("inside of paintComponent"); 
             System.out.println("chargeSnakestate : "+ snakeColouuuur+"   "+x_start+"   "+ y_start );
             g.setColor(snakeColouuuur);
             g.fillRect(x_start, y_start, 10, 10);
         }
         if(dischargeSnakestate)
         {
             System.out.println("inside of paintComponent");
             g.setColor(backgroundColor);
             g.fillRect(x_start, y_start, 10, 10);
         }
         if(putFeedState)
         {
             System.out.println("inside of paintComponent");
             g.setColor(feedColor);
             g.fillRect(x_start, y_start, 10, 10);
         }
         Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
         g.dispose();

         chargeSnakestate=false;
         dischargeSnakestate=false;
         putFeedState=false;
     }    
}
```

My JFrame :

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
public class Snake_Form extends JFrame {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6139997831592727657L;

    private JPanel contentPane;

    private Snake []snake;
    private Grafik grafik;

    int numberOfPlayer=1;
    int maxNumberOfPlayer=2;
    boolean gameSituation=false;
    private JLabel lblFirstPlayerScore;
    private JLabel lblSecondPlayerScore;

    Color[] clr = {new Color(255,0,0)/*red*/,new Color(0,255,0)/*green*/,new Color(0,0,255)/*blue*/};

    private Timer gameTimer;
    private Timer waitTimer;

    int speed = 1;

    public Semaphore semaphore;

    public Snake[] getSnake() {
        return snake;
    }

    public void setSnake(Snake[] snake) {
        this.snake = snake;
    }

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Snake_Form frame = new Snake_Form();
                    frame.pack();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Snake_Form() {
        setResizable(false);
        System.out.println("Snake_FORM");

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        setTitle("SNAKE GAME");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu mnGame = new JMenu("Game");
        menuBar.add(mnGame);

        JMenuItem start = new JMenuItem("Start");
        start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("start menu item ına basıldı");

                if(!gameSituation)
                {
                    newGame();
                }
                else
                {
                    gameTimer.setDelay(150);
                    gameTimer.start();
                }
            }
        });
        mnGame.add(start);

        JMenuItem stop = new JMenuItem("Stop");
        stop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("stop menu item ına basıldı");
                gameTimer.stop();
            }
        });
        mnGame.add(stop);

        JMenuItem newGame = new JMenuItem("New Game");
        newGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("new game menu item ına basıldı");
                newGame();
            }
        });
        mnGame.add(newGame);

        JMenu mnSpeed = new JMenu("Speed");
        menuBar.add(mnSpeed);

        JMenuItem level1 = new JMenuItem("Level  1");
        level1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Level 1 menu item ına basıldı");
                speed = 1;
                gameTimer.setDelay(150);
                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayer; i++)
                {
                    snake[i].snakeSpeed=speed;
                }
            }
        });
        mnSpeed.add(level1);

        JMenuItem level2 = new JMenuItem("Level  2");
        level2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Level 2 menu item ına basıldı");
                speed = 2;
                gameTimer.setDelay(130);
                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayer; i++)
                {
                    snake[i].snakeSpeed=speed;
                }
            }
        });
        mnSpeed.add(level2);

        JMenuItem level3 = new JMenuItem("Level  3");
        level3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("LEvel 3 menu item ına basıldı");
                speed = 3;
                gameTimer.setDelay(110);
                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayer; i++)
                {
                    snake[i].snakeSpeed=speed;
                }
            }
        });
        mnSpeed.add(level3);

        JMenuItem level4 = new JMenuItem("Level  4");
        level4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("level 4 menu item ına basıldı");
                speed = 4;
                gameTimer.setDelay(90);
                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayer; i++)
                {
                    snake[i].snakeSpeed=speed;
                }
            }
        });
        mnSpeed.add(level4);

        JMenuItem level5 = new JMenuItem("Level  5");
        level5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("level 5 menu item ına basıldı");
                speed = 5;
                gameTimer.setDelay(80);
                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayer; i++)
                {
                    snake[i].snakeSpeed=speed;
                }
            }
        });
        mnSpeed.add(level5);

        JMenuItem level6 = new JMenuItem("Level  6");
        level6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Level  6  menu item ına basıldı");
                speed = 6;
                gameTimer.setDelay(70);
                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayer; i++)
                {
                    snake[i].snakeSpeed=speed;
                }
            }
        });
        mnSpeed.add(level6);

        JMenuItem level7 = new JMenuItem("Level  7");
        level7.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Level 7  menu item ına basıldı");
                speed = 7;
                gameTimer.setDelay(60);
                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayer; i++)
                {
                    snake[i].snakeSpeed=speed;
                }
            }
        });
        mnSpeed.add(level7);

        JMenuItem level8 = new JMenuItem("Level  8");
        level8.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Level 8  menu item ına basıldı");
                speed = 8;
                gameTimer.setDelay(50);
                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayer; i++)
                {
                    snake[i].snakeSpeed=speed;
                }
            }
        });
        mnSpeed.add(level8);

        JMenuItem level9 = new JMenuItem("Level  9");
        level9.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Level 9  menu item ına basıldı");
                speed = 9;
                gameTimer.setDelay(40);
                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayer; i++)
                {
                    snake[i].snakeSpeed=speed;
                }

            }
        });
        mnSpeed.add(level9);

        JMenu mnPlayer = new JMenu("Player");
        menuBar.add(mnPlayer);

        JMenuItem mntmOnePlayer = new JMenuItem("One Player");
        mntmOnePlayer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("One Player menu item ına basıldı");
                numberOfPlayer = 1;
                lblFirstPlayerScore.setVisible(true);
                lblSecondPlayerScore.setVisible(false);
                lblFirstPlayerScore.setText("Birinci Oyuncu PUAN : " + snake[0].score );

                newGame();
            }
        });
        mnPlayer.add(mntmOnePlayer);

        JMenuItem mntmTwoPlayer = new JMenuItem("Two Player");
        mntmTwoPlayer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Two Player menu item ına basıldı");

                numberOfPlayer = 2;
                lblFirstPlayerScore.setVisible(true);
                lblSecondPlayerScore.setVisible(true);
                lblFirstPlayerScore.setText("Birinci Oyuncu PUAN : " + snake[0].score );
                lblSecondPlayerScore.setText("ikinci Oyuncu PUAN : " + snake[1].score );
                newGame();
            }
        });
        mnPlayer.add(mntmTwoPlayer);

        JMenu mnHelp = new JMenu("Help");
        menuBar.add(mnHelp);

        final JMenuItem learnGame = new JMenuItem("Learn Game");
        learnGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(learnGame, "        Game starts when the user select the “Player” menu \nfrom the game board and choose how many people\nhe/she will want to play.\n\n        Joy pad will be appointed for the -One Player- \nand E,S,F,D will be appointed for the -Second Player- \nto play the game. (E->Up S->Left F->Right D->Down).","Learn Game",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        });
        mnHelp.add(learnGame);

        final JMenuItem aboutGame = new JMenuItem("About Game");
        aboutGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(aboutGame, "Snake Game written by Merve =)", "About Game", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        });

        mnHelp.add(aboutGame);

        contentPane = new JPanel();

//      contentPane.setSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        contentPane.setBounds(0,0,400,400);
        contentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        lblFirstPlayerScore = new JLabel("lblFirstPlayerScore");
        lblFirstPlayerScore.setBounds(10, 0, 150, 25);
        lblFirstPlayerScore.setVisible(false);          //when the game is loaded score does not seem
        contentPane.add(lblFirstPlayerScore);

        lblSecondPlayerScore = new JLabel("lblSecondPlayerScore");
        lblSecondPlayerScore.setBounds(10, 25, 150, 25);
        lblSecondPlayerScore.setVisible(false);         //when the game is loaded score does not seem
        contentPane.add(lblSecondPlayerScore);


        grafik= new Grafik();

        grafik.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) snake[1].route=1;
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) snake[1].route=2;
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_UP) snake[1].route=3;
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) snake[1].route=4;
                //if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape) Application.Exit();

                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_S) snake[1].route=1;
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_F) snake[1].route=2;
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_E) snake[1].route=3;
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_D) snake[1].route=4;

                for(int i=0;i<numberOfPlayer;i++)
                {
                    snake[i].waitInt=20;
                }
                waitTimer.stop(); 
                gameTimer.start();  
            }
        });

        grafik.createGraphicYard(); 

        grafik.feed.x=-1;
        grafik.feed.y=-1;
        grafik.isThereFeed=false;

        contentPane.add(grafik);


        //when the game is loaded 2 Snake Object is set
        snake= new Snake[maxNumberOfPlayer];




        //start the game with one player
        for(int i=0; i<maxNumberOfPlayer;i++)
        {
            snake[i]= new Snake();
        }

        //Create a timer.
        gameTimer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                gameTickerTick();
            }
        });

        //Create a timer.
        waitTimer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                waitTimerTick();
            }
        });

        semaphore= new Semaphore(1);
    }

    void newGame()
    {
        System.out.println("new Game icindeyim");

        gameTimer.stop();

        grafik.createGraphicYard();
        grafik.isThereFeed=false;

        for(int i=0; i<numberOfPlayer;i++)
        {
            snake[i].length=5;
            snake[i].tailLength=5;
            snake[i].x=5+i*5;
            snake[i].y=5+i*5;
            snake[i].route=2-i;
            snake[i].score=0;
            snake[i].defaultSnake();
            snake[i].snakeColor = clr[i];
        }

        gameSituation=true;
        gameTimer.start();
    }

    private void snakeGameIsOver() {
        System.out.println("oyun bitti");
        gameSituation=false;
        try {
            gameTimer.wait(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(!gameSituation)
            gameTimer.stop();
        else
            gameTimer.start();

        if(numberOfPlayer==1)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(lblFirstPlayerScore, "Game is over...");
        else
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(lblFirstPlayerScore+"\n"+lblSecondPlayerScore, "Game is over..");
        lblFirstPlayerScore.setText("SCORE: "+snake[0].score);
        grafik.createGraphicYard();
        grafik.isThereFeed=gameSituation;
        if(!gameSituation)
            gameTimer.stop();
        else
            gameTimer.start();
    }

    void gameTickerTick()
    {
        System.out.println(" In gametimer");    

        try {
            semaphore.acquire();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for(int i=0;i<numberOfPlayer;i++)
        {
            //shift the snake one unit to its route
            if(snake[i].route==1) snake[i].snakeGoesLeft();
            if(snake[i].route==2) snake[i].snakeGoesRight();
            if(snake[i].route==3) snake[i].snakeGoesUp();
            if(snake[i].route==4) snake[i].snakeGoesDown();

            //when the game area border ends permits the snake pass other side
            if(snake[i].x>39) snake[i].x=0;
            else if(snake[i].x<0) snake[i].x=40;

            if(snake[i].y>39) snake[i].y=0;
            else if(snake[i].y<0) snake[i].y=40;

            System.out.println("I will charge");            
            //charge the snake
            grafik.chargeSnake(snake[i].x,snake[i].y,snake[i].snakeColor);
            System.out.println("I have charged");

            //adds the added unit to tail of snake
            snake[i].areaX[snake[i].tailLength]=snake[i].x;
            snake[i].areaY[snake[i].tailLength]=snake[i].y;
            snake[i].tailLength++;

            System.out.println("I will discharged");
            //discharge the snake
            grafik.dischargeSnake(snake[i].areaX[snake[i].tailLength-snake[i].length], snake[i].areaY[snake[i].tailLength-snake[i].length]);
            System.out.println("I have discharged");


            if(snake[i].tailLength>899)
            {
                snake[i].tailLength=snake[i].length;
                for(int z=0;z<snake[i].length;++z)
                {
                    snake[i].areaX[snake[i].length-z]=snake[i].areaX[900-z];
                    snake[i].areaY[snake[i].length-z]=snake[i].areaY[900-z];
                }
            }

            if((grafik.isSnakeTookFeed(snake[i].x, snake[i].y)==false)&&(grafik.isThereFeed==false))
            {
                //create new feed and its coordinate
                grafik.specifyFeedCoordinate();
                grafik.putFeed(grafik.feed.x,grafik.feed.y);
                grafik.isThereFeed=true;
            }

            if(grafik.isSnakeTookFeed(snake[i].x, snake[i].y)==true)
            {
                grafik.feed.x=-1;
                grafik.feed.y=-1;
                grafik.isThereFeed=false;
                snake[i].score+=1*snake[i].snakeSpeed;
                snake[i].length+=1;
                if(i==0)
                    lblFirstPlayerScore.setText("First Player Score: "+snake[i].score);
                else if(i==1)
                    lblSecondPlayerScore.setText("Second Player Score: "+snake[i].score);               
            }
        }

        for(int i=0;i<numberOfPlayer;i++)
        {
            if(snake[i].isSnakeCrashedItself(contentPane)==true)
            {
                gameTimer.stop();;
                waitTimer.start();

                if(snake[i].waitInt<=0)
                {                       
                }
                else
                {
                    snake[i].waitInt=20;
                }
            }               
        }
        semaphore.release();
    }

    void waitTimerTick()
    {
        System.out.println("wait timer");
        for(int i=0;i<numberOfPlayer;i++)
        {
            snake[i].waitInt--;
            if(snake[i].waitInt==0)
            {
                waitTimer.stop();
                snakeGameIsOver();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Snake Object:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Snake 
{
    public Color snakeColor;
    public int route;
    public int length,tailLength;
    public int x,y,snakeSpeed;
    public int score;
    public int waitInt;
    public int[] areaX= new int[1000];
    public int[] areaY= new int[1000];

    protected Random randomm;

    //Snake constructor
    public Snake()
    {
        snakeColor= Color.BLUE;
        snakeSpeed=1;
        randomm= new Random();
        System.out.println("Snake has been constructed.");
    }

    //turn the snake right side
    public void snakeGoesRight()
    {
        this.x+=1;
    }
    //turn the snake left side
    public void snakeGoesLeft()
    {
        this.x-=1;
    }
    //turn the snake upper
    public void snakeGoesUp()
    {
        this.y-=1;
    }
    //turn the snake down side
    public void snakeGoesDown()
    {
        this.y+=1;
    }

    //check the snake if it s crashed itself or not
    public boolean isSnakeCrashedItself(JPanel jpanel)
    {
        System.out.println("inside of isSnakeCrashedItself function");
        Dimension size = jpanel.getSize();
        int imageType = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB;
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(size.width, size.height, imageType);
        Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
        jpanel.paint(g2d);

        boolean situation= false;
        int x= this.x*10;
        int y=this.y*10;

        try
        {
            if(route==1)
            {
                if((!Color.WHITE.equals(new Color(image.getRGB(x-5,y+5)))))
                {
                    situation=true;
                }
                else
                    situation=false;
            }
            if(route==2)
            {
                if((!Color.WHITE.equals(new Color(image.getRGB(x+15, y+5)))))
                {
                    situation=true;
                }
                else
                    situation=false;
            }
            if(route==3)
            {
                if((!Color.WHITE.equals(new Color(image.getRGB(x+5, y-5)))))
                {
                    situation=true;
                }
                else
                    situation=false;
            }
            if(route==4)
            {
                if((!Color.WHITE.equals(new Color(image.getRGB(x+5, y+15)))))
                {
                    situation=true;
                }
                else
                    situation=false;
            }       
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //e.message
            return false;
        }
        return situation;
    }
    //it makes the snake s properties default
    public void defaultSnake()
    {
        System.out.println("inside of default snake function");

        areaX=null;
        areaY=null;

        areaX= new int[1000];
        areaY=new int[1000];

        for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
        {
            areaX[i]=0;
            areaY[i]=0;
        }
    }
}
```

The console output :

```
I will charge
inside of chargesnake
chargeSnake1 : java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]   6   5
I have charged
I will discharged
inside of dischargesnake
I have discharged
inside of isSnakeTookFeed
inside of specifyFeedCoordinate
inside of paintComponent
chargeSnakestate : java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]   0   0
inside of paintComponent
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at Grafik.specifyFeedCoordinate(Grafik.java:117)
    at Snake_Form.gameTickerTick(Snake_Form.java:498)
    at Snake_Form$19.actionPerformed(Snake_Form.java:378)
    at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Nb: in 15 years of Sing development, I've never used Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync(); and disposing of a graphics context you did not create could result in nothing being painted on some systems...you should never call paint directly, this is not how custom painting is done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     int rnd=random.nextInt(possiblePlacesX.size()+1);
     feed.x=possiblePlacesX.get(rnd);

     // ...

     feed.y=possiblePlacesY.get(rnd);
```

See what you are doing here? You might end up getting a value for `rnd` that is the same as the size of your lists, and this will of course get you the nice stack trace you have above.

In your exact case, your lists are empty (`size() == 0`), and you are trying to access item `0`. Instead you should just handle this case (empty lists) and (probably) do nothing.

There's other issues in your code too, like the ones mentioned by @MadProgrammer, I won't go into details...

Comment: Thank you very much, i checked and found my fault.I had changed panel background color as pink. While i was checking possible feed points,it returns empty lists because it controls due to white backgroud color.